# Simplify conditional integrals in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

In SymPy, if I integrate a general Gaussian by:

```
x = Symbol("x", real=True)
y = Symbol("y", real=True)
s = Symbol("s", real=True)

gaussian = exp(-((x-y)**2)/(2*(s**2)))
nfactor = simplify(integrate(gaussian, (x,-oo,oo)))
```

I get `nfactor` as `Piecewise` dependent on `periodic_argument` and `polar_lift`. A object the same as made by:

```
Abs(periodic_argument(polar_lift(s)**(-2), oo))
```

must be less than `pi/2` for the solution I want. Is there a nice way to only have this condition - in Mathematica one might use `Assuming` and `Refine` or `Simplify`, but I'm new to sympy and I don't know what to do here.

Comment: For me, it already simplifies with the assumptions you have.

Comment: @asmeurer Hello again ;) ... Typo - should have been the definite integral over (-oo, oo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `s` to be positive should be enough. Really, I think the answer should be in terms of `Abs(s)`, since for real `s`, `sqrt(s**2) = Abs(s)` (I'm not positive about that, though).

In the git master branch of SymPy, you can use refine to manually assume the exact condition you want

```
In [6]: refine(nfactor, Q.is_true(Abs(periodic_argument(1/polar_lift(s)**2, oo)) <= pi/2))
Out[6]:
  ___   ___
╲╱ 2 ⋅╲╱ π ⋅s
```

Another way, if you know that your integral satisfies the conditions, but you can't get them to simplify (because unfortunately, simplification of such conditions in SymPy is very poor), you can just use `integrate(conds='none')`, or `integrate(conds='separate')` (this does not require the git version to work.

```
In [8]: integrate(gaussian, (x,-oo,oo), conds='none')
Out[8]:
  ___   ___
╲╱ 2 ⋅╲╱ π ⋅s

In [9]: integrate(gaussian, (x,-oo,oo), conds='separate')
Out[9]:
⎛  ___   ___    │                 ⎛      1          ⎞│   π⎞
⎜╲╱ 2 ⋅╲╱ π ⋅s, │periodic_argument⎜──────────────, ∞⎟│ ≤ ─⎟
⎜               │                 ⎜          2      ⎟│   2⎟
⎝               │                 ⎝polar_lift (s)   ⎠│    ⎠
```

You can also just pull it out of the Piecewise

```
In [10]: nfactor.args[0][0]
Out[10]:
  ___   ___
╲╱ 2 ⋅╲╱ π ⋅s
```

The preferred way, of course, will be to use `refine`, but unfortunately, things using the new assumptions system (anything using `Q`) are still in development, so may not work yet, or may only work in the SymPy development version.

Answer (score 4):

The answer involves a square root of the square of `Symbol` bound to `s`.

Declare `s` positive to make it simplify properly. By:

```
s = Symbol('sigma', real=True, positive=True)
```